# Transferring parameters learned using one model to another

Tags: regression, logistic, neural-networks, svm, model-selection

I am watching this video lecture by Andrew NG on *"Getting Machine Learning Algorithms to work in Practice"* and I am stuck at the following two slides:

The problem discussed is as follows: Let's say an SVM outperforms Logistic Regression. How do I know if there is a problem with my 'optimization' or 'optimization function'?

[image]

[image]

He suggests to use $\theta_{svm}$ that were learned using SVM in the optimization function of logistic regression. Coincidentally, for both SVM and Logistic Regression, $\theta$s are the weights of linear features. And therefore, I can use $\theta$s learned using SVM into the optimization function of linear regression.

**Question**: What if $\theta$s are not that straightforward to transfer? For example: what if I want to compare a Neural Network model with Linear Regression?

Timestamped link to the video: https://youtu.be/sQ8T9b-uGVE?t=2703